# Erro no cadastro de usuários, alterando o usuário ao invés inserir

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Meu problema é o seguinte, vi que quando edito um registro , funciona, o cadastro é alterado, mas quando eu quero cadastrar um novo usuário, ele cai na condição de edição, ele edita as informações do cadastro que eu estava alterando anteriormente, não deixando cadastrar um novo usuário, porque isso acontece?

Variável responsável por validar se está editando ou não.

```
private int codigoEditar = 0;
```

Método responsável por buscar o código do usuário na tabela.

```
JButton button_3 = new JButton("Editar");
        button_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(0);

                // Variável responsável por capturar a linha selecionada
                int linhaSelecionada = -1;
                // Busca a linha selecionada e armazena na variável
                // linhaSelecionada(tr)
                //
                linhaSelecionada = tabela.getSelectedRow();

                // Validar se uma linha foi selecionada
                if (linhaSelecionada >= 0) {
                    // Armazena a informação da primeira coluna da linha
                    // selecionada(td)
                    //coluna 0 código do funcionário
                    int codigoFuncionario = (int) tabela.getValueAt(linhaSelecionada, 0);

                buscarFuncionario(codigoFuncionario);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selecione uma " + "linha para alterar o Funcionário!");
                }
            }
        });
```

Método que recebe como parâmetro o código do funcionário, colocando as informações do usuário na tela de cadastro para alteração.

```
//recebe como parâmetro o código do funcionário
    protected void buscarFuncionario(int codigoFuncionario) {
         control.Funcionarios func = new control.Funcionarios();
         //laço foreach que percorre o arraylist referenciando o código do funcionário
         for (Funcionarios  funcio : func.listarFuncionarios(codigoFuncionario + "", 1)) {

             /*Funcionarios funcio é o Dao, para setar(set) e pegar(get)
              * func.listarFuncionarios(codigoFuncionario + "", 1)) códigoFuncionário + "" concatena o código com o parametro texto da pesquisa da 
              * classe control
              * 1 é a pesquisa por código do funcionário referenciando o parametro do código do funcionário
              */




             // Setar informações na tela de cadastro
                nome.setText(funcio.getNome());
                email.setText(funcio.getEmail());
                endereco.setText(funcio.getEndereco());
                telefone.setText(funcio.getTelefone());
                cpf.setText(funcio.getCpf_funcionario());



                //Variável que recebe o valor do codigo do usuário
                //importante para a alteração
                codigoEditar = funcio.getCodigo_funcionario();

            }

            cadastro.setVisible(true);
            listagem.setVisible(false);

        }
```

Método responsável por salvar ou alterar o funcionário.

```
protected void salvar() {
                // Capturar informações que o usuário digitou
                String nome_funcionario = nome.getText();
                String cpf_funcionario = cpf.getText();
                String endereco_funcionario = endereco.getText();
                String email_funcionario = email.getText();
                String fone_funcionario = telefone.getText();
                String senha_funcionario = senha.getText();
                String rep_senha_funcionario= repsenha.getText();
                if(email_funcionario.equals("")&& cpf_funcionario.equals("")&&fone_funcionario.equals("")&&nome_funcionario.equals("")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Preencha os campos");

                }else if(!rep_senha_funcionario.equals(senha_funcionario)){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "As senhas são diferentes");

                    //validar se as senhas são iguais
                }else if(endereco_funcionario.equals("")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O campo Endereço é Obrigatório!");
                }

                      // Criando o objeto 

 Funcionarios func = new Funcionarios();

                func.setNome(nome_funcionario);
                func.setEmail(email_funcionario);
                func.setTelefone(fone_funcionario);
                func.setSenha(senha_funcionario);
                func.setEndereco(endereco_funcionario);
                func.setCpf_funcionario(cpf_funcionario);
                func.setCodigo_funcionario(codigoEditar);

                control.Funcionarios manutencao = new control.Funcionarios();

            //validar se estamos cadastrando ou editando os registros
                if(codigoEditar == 0){
                    manutencao.inserir(func);

                }else{
                    manutencao.alterar(func);

                }

                limparInformacoes();
                tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(1);

            }
        }
```

Classe Dao

```
package dao;

public class Funcionarios {

    private int codigo_funcionario;
    private String cpf_funcionario;
    private String email;
    private String endereco;
    private String nome;
    private String senha;
    private String telefone;

    public int getCodigo_funcionario() {
        return codigo_funcionario;
    }
    public void setCodigo_funcionario(int codigo_funcionario) {
        this.codigo_funcionario = codigo_funcionario;
    }
    public String getCpf_funcionario() {
        return cpf_funcionario;
    }
    public void setCpf_funcionario(String cpf_funcionario) {
        this.cpf_funcionario = cpf_funcionario;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }
    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }
    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }
    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }
    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }
}
```

Método de salvar do pacote control da classe funcionários

```
public void inserir(dao.Funcionarios func) {
        if (func != null) {
            // Variável de conexão de DB
            java.sql.Connection conn = null;

            try {
                conn = ConnectDB.conexaoDB();

                java.sql.PreparedStatement pstm;

                pstm = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT);
                pstm.setString(1, func.getCpf_funcionario());
                pstm.setString(2, func.getEmail());
                pstm.setString(3, func.getSenha());
                pstm.setString(4, func.getNome());
                pstm.setString(5, func.getEndereco());
                pstm.setString(6, func.getTelefone());

                // Envia para o banco de dados
                Boolean teste;
                teste = pstm.execute();

                // Validar inserção no banco de dados
                if (!teste) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Funcionario cadastrado com sucesso!");

                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao cadastrar o Funcionario!");
                }

                // Fecha a conexão com o banco de dados
                ConnectDB.fecharConexao(conn);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao cadastrar o Funcionario!");

            }

        }

    }
```

Método de alterar do pacote control da classe funcionários

```
//parametro objeto dao.funcionarios
public void alterar(dao.Funcionarios func) {
    java.sql.Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = ConnectDB.conexaoDB();

        //prepara a query
        java.sql.PreparedStatement pstm;

        pstm = conn.prepareStatement(UPDATE);
        pstm.setString(1, func.getCpf_funcionario());
        pstm.setString(2, func.getEmail());
        pstm.setString(3, func.getNome());
        pstm.setString(4, func.getEndereco());
        pstm.setString(5, func.getTelefone());
    pstm.setString(6, func.getSenha());
        pstm.setInt(7, func.getCodigo_funcionario());

        // Envia para o banco de dados
        Boolean teste;
        teste = pstm.execute();

        // Validar inserção no banco de dados
        if (!teste) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Funcionario alterado com sucesso!");

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao alterar o funcionario!");
        }

        // Fecha a conexão com o banco de dados
        ConnectDB.fecharConexao(conn);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao alterar o funcionario!"+e.getMessage());

    }



}
```

Comment: Peço ajuda de vocês para corrigir o problema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, ele está cadastrando normalmente, porém após a edição de qualquer cadastro, ele não cadastra novamente, ele apenas edita o cadastro anterior, caso seja isto, segue a solução:

No método responsável por salvar, ou editar um registro:

```
if(codigoEditar == 0){
    manutencao.inserir(func);
}else{
    manutencao.alterar(func);
}
```

Só entrará na condição de inserir, caso o `codigoEditar` seja igual a *zero*.

Solução: Após alterar o cadastro, basta zerar a variável `codigoEditar`, você pode fazer isso de diversas formas, tanto zerando ao clicar em algum botão `cadastrar`, ou zerando após finalizar a alteração do cadastro.

Sugestão: Ao invés de definir a variável `codigoEditar`, como `inteiro`, você pode defini-la como `booleana`, considerando que ela seja apenas `true` ou `false`. Simplificando o If e Else.

```
if(codigoEditar){
     manutencao.inserir(func);
}else{
     manutencao.alterar(func);
}
```

Comment: Sua solução funcionou, coloquei o codigoEditar no else, obrigado pela ajuda!.

Comment: Precisando, estamos aí!